# On focus or onclick button not refreshing playlist from Json parser URL

Tags: android, json, parsing, fetch, onfocus

How to achieve this guys?
I have two buttons om my app.

1. Button1 fetch/retrieve All Videos playlist from Json file on URL called VideoAll.js
2. Button2 fetch/retrieve UK Videos playlist from Json file on URL called VideoUK.js

My code is working and its fetching the playlist when I click All (VideoAll.js) button, but when I click UK button its not refreshing and I get the same list from VideoAll.js I have to close the app and open to click UK button first to get the correct playlist from VideoUK.js, but again I cant get the list from All. Basically its not refreshing or updating onclick or even onfocus. its calling Json every time I click so I am sure this is not the way is done and I am doing it wrong.

**MyActivity**

```
public class VideoPlayerActivity extends Activity implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
//private Toolbar toolbar;
private ListView mDrawerList;
private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
private RelativeLayout mDrawerRelativeLayout;

public static final String EXTRA_INDEX = "EXTRA_INDEX";
public static final int PLAYLIST_ID = 6; //Arbitrary, for the example (different from audio)
protected EMVideoView emVideoView;
protected PlaylistManager playlistManager;

protected int selectedIndex = 2;//Auto play first video
private final String VIDEO_URL1 = "http://satdoc.dyndns.info/all.js";
private final String VIDEO_URL2 = "http://satdoc.dyndns.info/uk.js";


private String TAG = "VideoPlayerActivity";
List<VideoItem> videoList = new ArrayList<>();
private FullScreenListener fullScreenListener;
//private Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.video_player_activity);
    setVolumeControlStream(3);

    mDrawerTitle = getTitle();


    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.selection_activity_list);
    mDrawerRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    emVideoView = (EMVideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_play_activity_video_view);
    emVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(this);


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        fullScreenListener = new FullScreenListener();
    }

    goFullscreen();
    emVideoView.setVideoViewControlsCallback(new DefaultControlsCallback());

    initDrawer();

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);



    btn.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (hasFocus) {
                fetchVideos1();
            }
        }

    });


    btn2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (hasFocus) {
                fetchVideos2();
            }
        }

    });

 }


/**
 * Fetch for videos online.
 */
public void fetchVideos1() {
    if (NetworkConnectionStatus.isOnline(this)) {//If there is internet connection, load reviews through a http request.
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.setTimeout(20_000);
        client.get(VIDEO_URL1, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                // called before request is started

            }

            @Override

            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {// called when response HTTP status is "200 OK"
                String jsonResponse = new String(response);



                try {


                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonResponse);
                    JSONObject jsonObject;
                    String videoTitle, videoUrl;
                    int videoNum;
                    int length = jsonArray.length();


                    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {


                        jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
                        videoTitle = jsonObject.getString("chname");
                        videoUrl = jsonObject.getString("chlink");
                        videoNum = jsonObject.getInt("chid");

                        VideoItem videoItem = new VideoItem(videoTitle, videoUrl, videoNum);
                        videoList.add(videoItem);
                    }


                    setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                    init();
                    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new VideoSelectionListAdapter(VideoPlayerActivity.this, videoList));

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
                }

                progressDialog.dismiss();

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] errorResponse, Throwable e) {

                Toast.makeText(VideoPlayerActivity.this, "A server error occured, Try again later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onRetry(int retryNo) {
                // called when request is retried
            }
        });

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(VideoPlayerActivity.this, "No internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}




public void fetchVideos2() {
    if (NetworkConnectionStatus.isOnline(this)) {//If there is internet connection, load reviews through a http request.
        final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);



        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.setTimeout(20_000);
        client.get(VIDEO_URL2, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                // called before request is started

            }

            @Override

            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {// called when response HTTP status is "200 OK"
                String jsonResponse = new String(response);



                try {


                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonResponse);
                    JSONObject jsonObject;
                    String videoTitle, videoUrl;
                    int videoNum;
                    int length = jsonArray.length();


                    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {


                        jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
                        videoTitle = jsonObject.getString("chname");
                        videoUrl = jsonObject.getString("chlink");
                        videoNum = jsonObject.getInt("chid");

                        VideoItem videoItem = new VideoItem(videoTitle, videoUrl, videoNum);
                        videoList.add(videoItem);
                    }


                    setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                    init();
                    mDrawerList.setAdapter(new VideoSelectionListAdapter(VideoPlayerActivity.this, videoList));

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
                }

                progressDialog.dismiss();

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] errorResponse, Throwable e) {

                Toast.makeText(VideoPlayerActivity.this, "A server error occured, Try again later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onRetry(int retryNo) {
                // called when request is retried
            }
        });

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(VideoPlayerActivity.this, "No internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}
```

And here is my 2nd Json file on the server (VideoUK.js)

```
[
{
    "chid": 1,
    "chname": "UK1",
    "chlogo": "",
    "chlink": "http://samplevideoUK1.mp4",
    "chenable": "",
    "chnote": ""
},
{
    "chid": 2,
    "chname": "UK 2",
    "chlogo": "",
    "chlink": "http://samplevideoUK2.mp4",
    "chenable": "",
    "chnote": ""
},
{
    "chid": 3,
    "chname": "UK 3",
    "chlogo": "",
    "chlink": "http://samplevideoUK3.mp4",
    "chenable": "",
    "chnote":

}
]
```

and here is (VideoAll.js)

```
    [
{
    "chid": 1,
    "chname": "Video 1",
    "chlogo": "",
    "chlink": "http://samplevideo1.mp4",
    "chenable": "",
    "chnote": ""
},
{
    "chid": 2,
    "chname": "Video 2",
    "chlogo": "",
    "chlink": "http://samplevideo2.mp4",
    "chenable": "",
    "chnote": ""
},
{
    "chid": 3,
    "chname": "RO 3",
    "chlogo": "",
    "chlink": "http://samplevideo3.mp4",
    "chenable": "",
    "chnote":
}
]
```

and finally my buttons in my layout

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="All"
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_weight="1" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/uk"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:choiceMode="none"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:fadeScrollbars="false"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

Can someone please at least show an example of how to call json and get the list every time we click the button refreshed?. Only the button that is clicked first works but after that nothing changes when I click. sorry for repeating but its driving me mad.

[Screenshot of my ap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DjbS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly clear video list on button click

```
     btn.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (hasFocus) {
videoList.clear();
                    fetchVideos1();
                }
            }

        });


        btn2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (hasFocus) {
videoList.clear();
                    fetchVideos2();
                }
            }

        });
```

and notify data set chenge after setting adapter in webservices like:

```
mDrawerList.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Please Use this After This lines in your code :

```
setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                init();
                mDrawerList.setAdapter(new VideoSelectionListAdapter(VideoPlayerActivity.this, videoList));

notifyDataSetChanged();
```

it is used to refresh adapter

also clear list on vutton click

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Ashish! May ask you where should I use this code mDrawerList.notifyDataSetChanged(); I am a total noob dear please help me.

Comment: My God Ashish !! You are a super star and saved me a lot. Its working now just after adding videoList.clear(); on every VideoFetch I cant believe it, but I am learning android step by step from guys like you.Thank You Dear. My I ask you why do I need the last line you mentioned? I will try it and see how it goes.

Comment: Hi Ashis , Its working and updating the list but the funny behavior I am getting is when opening the drawer its starting to play first video from All on every time I want to change video. Do you know how to be on the last selected video category (UK) as well as last selected video (UK1) so i can control the drawer?

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged is red when I entered that code , I am not sure where I am missing dear. as I said its making it impossible to change category when drawer is opening.

Comment: notyfy data set change working with your adapter try to do

Comment: Do I need to type anything before that code because I am getting red text as something is missing, I've just paste it where you told me maybe  notifyDataSetChanged must be created? I am getting the question mark on android studio, maybe import needed?lol I'm total newbie Ashish sorry.

Comment: define VideoSelectionListAdapter adapter as gobel variable and then use this.